# Grep Print Only After Match

Tags: bash, grep

I used `grep` that outputs a list like this

```
/player/ABc12
/player/ABC321
/player/EGF987
/player/egf751
```

However I want to only give the name of the players such `ABC321`, `EFG987`, etc...

Comment: grep only shows you the lines that contain what you found. usually you'd use awk/sed to filter things so you only get the sub-parts of the line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@sputnick has the right idea with `grep`, and something like that would actually be my preferred solution.  I personally immediately thought of a positive lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=/player/)\w+' file
```

But the `\K` works perfectly fine as well.

An alternative (somewhat shorter) solution is with `sed`:

```
sed 's:.*/::' file
```

Comment: the sed expression worked out better for me

Answer (score 26):

Start using `grep` :

```
$ grep -oP "/player/\K.*" FILE
ABc12
ABC321
EGF987
egf751
```

Or shorter :

```
$ grep -oP "[^/]/\K.*" FILE
ABc12
ABC321
EGF987
egf751
```

Or without `-P` (pcre) option :

```
$ grep -o '[^/]\+$' FILE
ABc12
ABC321
EGF987
egf751
```

Or with pure `bash` :

```
$ IFS=/ oIFS=$IFS
$ while read a b c; do echo $c; done < FILE
ABc12
ABC321
EGF987
egf751
$ IFS=$oIFS
```

Answer (score 5):

Stop using grep.

```
$ awk -F/ '$2 == "player" { print $3 }' input.txt
ABc12
ABC321
EGF987
egf751
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `GNU grep` and a positive lookbehind:

```
grep -oP '(?<=^/player/).*' file.txt
```

Results:

```
ABc12
ABC321
EGF987
egf751
```